# Import dll into Unity "file inaccessible" or "not valid assembly"

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, dll

I am trying to import a dll into my Unity project. I have the dll copied into the Assets folder. When I try to "Add Reference" in Visual Studio, I keep getting this error.

Can anyone point to what issue may be causing this error? The dll in question is from the [Native SDK for the Varjo headset](https://developer.varjo.com/docs/native/varjo-native-sdk). I am trying to import it so I can use the Native API from within my Unity project (requires functionality the Unity plugin does not provide).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't add the `.dll` to the references in visual project. Just drop it into your assets folder (better yet some subfolder).

To be able to use the relevant APIs from C# you will need to write a wrapper class similar to the one shown in this example:

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/NativePlugins.html

If you want you can give me a few examples of methods you want to call and I can show you how to expose them to c#.

Comment: I put the .dll into a subfolder in the assets folder and was able to successfully call a function from the SDK! It is really interesting that this works, even though Visual Studio insists the dll isn't valid.

Comment: That's most likely because VS expects a `managed` assembly while you are interfacing a `native` library.

Comment: How can I reference constants from the dll? The linked example refers to functions specifically. For example the API call in the docs (link): https://developer.varjo.com/docs/apidocs/_varjo_8h.html#abda813ee0d8883d97b5a8b62fe58ca9b is `varjo_Bool varjo_IsGazeAllowed (struct varjo_Session * session)`. How do I access the `varjo_Session` struct, which is defined in the dll?

Comment: From the short look I took into varjo doc `struct varjo_Session*` seems to just be an opaque pointer the framework keeps some internal data in. If that is indeed the case you need to initialize it using `varjo_SessionInit()` the managed declaration should look something like `extern static IntPtr SessionInit()` (add the DllImport attribute). Then you have to keep the returned IntPtr for the duration of the session. In any APIs requiring `varjo_Session` declare it as `IntPtr session`. Don't forget to shut down the session with `varjo_SessionShutDown(session)` when you're done with it.