# How to access compiled shader as DirectX blob in Unity C# script?

Tags: c#, c++, unity-game-engine, shader, hlsl

I need to access an HLSL shader as an ID3DBlob, and I am unsure how to do this in Unity.

**The example I am working from**

I am working with a native API in Unity, which I have imported using a .dll file using the technique [described here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/NativePlugins.html), per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71098621/import-dll-into-unity-file-inaccessible-or-not-valid-assembly/71099019#71099019). This API includes the following C++ call in the examples ([you can download from here](https://developer.varjo.com/downloads#native-developer-assets)):

```
varjo_MRD3D11ConfigureShader(m_session, m_d3d11Device.Get(), varjo_ShaderType_VideoPostProcess, &shaderConfig,
            (shaderBlob ? static_cast<char*>(shaderBlob->GetBufferPointer()) : nullptr),
            shaderBlob ? static_cast<int32_t>(shaderBlob->GetBufferSize()) : 0);
```

This is from the "Experimental API Video post-processing API" [some documentation here](https://developer.varjo.com/docs/native/video-post-processing) (you have to [download the "Varjo Experimental SDK for Custom Engines"](https://developer.varjo.com/downloads#native-developer-assets) and then navigate to the "/docs/_varjo__mr__experimental_8h.html#a01df1512b747fe2e8c75007ad5998d93" file for proper documentation). A screenshot of the full documentation follows:

[image]

I have determined that the `shaderData` parameter of type `const char *` is what contains the shader data being sent to the headset. The example code in the beginning of this question (taken from the linked developer-provided examples) passes in the data from the variable `shaderBlob`, which is of type `ID3DBlob` and is [documented as part of DirectX here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d3dcommon/nn-d3dcommon-id3d10blob).

In the developer-provided C++ example, the HLSL file is read in and converted to this `ID3DBlob` data structure by calling another DirectX function ([documented here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d3dcompiler/nf-d3dcompiler-d3dcompile)), `D3DCompile`:

```
LOG_INFO("Loading shader source: HLSL Source: %s", shaderFilename.c_str());
auto shaderData = loadFile(shaderFilename);
if (!shaderData.empty()) {
    ComPtr<ID3DBlob> errorMsgs;
    
    // The function of interest - comment my own...
    HRESULT hr = D3DCompile(shaderData.data(), shaderData.size(), shaderFilename.c_str(), nullptr, nullptr, c_shaderEntrypoint, c_shaderTarget, 0,
        0, &shaderBlob, &errorMsgs);
    // --------------------------------------------

    if (FAILED(hr) && errorMsgs) {
        std::string err(reinterpret_cast<char*>(errorMsgs->GetBufferPointer()), errorMsgs->GetBufferSize());
        LOG_ERROR("Compiling post process shader failed: %s", err.c_str());
        return false;
    }
} else {
    return false;
}
```

Microsoft also provides some additional [explanation of compiling shaders using DirectX here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3d11/how-to--compile-a-shader).

These developer-provided examples are all a stand-alone C++ app.

**What I am trying to do**

Using the [Unity documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/NativePlugins.html) and the `DllImport` [attribute documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute?view=net-6.0) and the [passing structs tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/passing-structures), I have set up the API call from my C# script as follows:

```
public class NativeSDKWrapper : MonoBehaviour
{
    #region Constants for DLL
    // ...

    /// <summary>
    /// See: http://[your localhost here]/_varjo__types__mr__experimental_8h.html
    /// </summary>
    private const Int64 VARJO_SHADER_TYPE_VIDEO_POST_PROCESS = 1;

    // ...
    #endregion

    #region Varjo Functions from DLL
    // ...

    [DllImport("VarjoLib")]
    private static extern void varjo_MRD3D11ConfigureShader(
        IntPtr session,
        IntPtr device,
        Int64 shaderType,
        ref VarjoShaderConfig shaderConfig, // I have defined the appropriate structs for this
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]string data, // See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39987435/pass-char-to-c-dll-from-c-sharp-string
        int shaderSize);

    // ...
    #endregion

    public void LoadShaderFromFile(ShaderParams shaderParams)
    {
        // Shader asset accessed here, and the Varjo lock acquired,
        //     and then shader config set up.
        // ...
        
        // Send the shader to the Varjo headset.
        varjo_MRD3D11ConfigureShader(
            this._session,
            , // Still need to figure out getting the device.
            NativeSDKWrapper.VARJO_SHADER_TYPE_VIDEO_POST_PROCESS,
            ref shaderConfig,
            , // WHAT GOES HERE??? (this is the string type translated from ID3DBlob.
              // The blob's (string's?) size will go here
        );

        // Varjo unlock here...
        // ...
    }
}
```

How do I get from a shader asset in my Unity Assets folder to the input string needed for that function call (so as type `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]string data`)? I went with the `string` to correspond with the screenshot above documenting that input as a `const char *`. Again, in the developer-provided C++ example this input is of type `ID3DBlob`.

Does Unity expose an equivalent to that DirectX shader compiling through `D3DCompile`? Does that question even make sense? Does Unity handle that compiling for me, and I can just grab the needed data as a string in the needed format from somewhere to put into this native API call?

I have also read through some of the [Unity DirectX documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/510/Documentation/Manual/DirectX11.html) but have not found it helpful.